# How to edit Electron instance's process name etc

Tags: javascript, electron, window, titlebar

So I want to make Electron's process have its own name, I mean when I go to tray while my application is running, its name is *electron*, and in equalizer software I see *chromium* process.

Is there any way to change its name to show something different than *electron* and *chromium*?

Here's my app:
[image: PulseEffects Electron App]

And here's Spotify, for comparison:
[image: PulseEffects Spotify Example]

Both are made in Electron. How does Spotify achieve this?

Comment: I recommand to turn those image link `[text][link]` into embedded images `![alt text][link]`

Comment: Not enough reputation points.